# Spring TransactionManager; what means isNewTransaction() exactly?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, transactionmanager

I am converting a legacy application to spring-boot. For the API-implementation I want to annotate it with @Transactional, but need to implement a custom transactionManager.

When I define:

```
@Component 
public class MyTransactionManager implements PlatformTransactionManager { ... }
```

the interface `PlatformTransactionManager` requires three methods be implemented...

`commit()` and `rollback()` are obvious.

But `getTransaction()` should return a type `TransactionStatus`
with a method  `boolean isNewTransaction()`

**What exactly is the purpose of this return value?**
When should it return `true` vs `false`?

**If I have no nested transaction, is it OK to always return true? (or always false?)**

Comment: Might not fully answer your question, but the docs do have a description of that method. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.M4_to_5.0.0.M5/Spring%20Framework%205.0.0.M5/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionStatus.html